# limit the number of searches

Tags: search

Can I limit the number of searches done on my WordPress site?

```
function fb_filter_query( $query, $error = true ) {
    if ( is_search() ) {
        $query->is_search       = false;
        $query->query_vars[s]   = false;
        $query->query[s]        = false;

        // to error
        if ( $error == true )
            $query->is_404 = true;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'fb_filter_query' );
add_filter( 'get_search_form', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
```

Comment: It might help to have a bit more detail. Are you trying to limit searches to a specific IP range? to registered, logged-in users only? to a specific number (eg, '10 searches every 24 hours')?

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to disable the search funcionality, right?

Comment: There is a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-search/) for that, you could take a look at the source to learn how they do it.

Comment: Yes @Pat J. Looking for it. 10 searches every 24 hours

Comment: @something if I don't add limit, I will disable search.

Comment: I found the answer in this blog post. [Wordpress Search Query Limit](https://www.teakolik.com/wordpress-arama-sorgularina-limit-koymak/)